# Nginx и модуль HTTP Push

Tags: nginx, ubuntu

Здравствуйте!

Я следую шагам, описанным в инструкции ([Используем Nginx как “long polling” (Comet) сервер](http://olemskoi.ru/node/3534)). Но я не могу понять, какой здесь задать путь: `-add-module=/path/to/nginx/modules/sources/nginx_http_push_module-`0.692/`

Сейчас мой `Nginx` на `/etc/nginx`, но тут нет каталога модулей.Можете ли Вы мне написать верные инструкции для установки Nginx+http_push модулей?

Спасибо!

Comment: Модуль-то как устанавливали? Если из исходников собирали, то вот там .../modules и должно быть! В смысле - там, где исходники.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Модель работы nginx не такая, сервер не поддерживает динамически загружаемые модули расширения. Вы похоже думаете, что загрузив модуль расширения и разместив его в папке nginx, он будет его использовать. Это не так, чтобы добавить модуль к nginx, нужно полностью компилировать nginx из исходных кодов с включенным и статически интегрированным в него новым модулем. Поэтому если с модулем поставляется сборщик, который загружает исходные код nginx и включается туда - запускайте его, например, модуль для *nginx* сервера приложений *phusion passenger*, где через `gem install passenger` в установленном геме запускается установщик

```
library/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-5.0.21/bin/passenger-install-nginx-module
```

Варианте установки 2 в параметрах *configure* указывается путь к нужным модулям `--add-module=путь_к_модулю1 --add-module=путь_к_модулю2` ... Или загрузив сбоку исходных кодов nginx и нужных вам модулей выполните

1. `cd nginx-версия`
2. `./configure --add-module=path/to/nginx_http_push_module --add-module=путь-к-другому-модулю`
3. `make`
4. `make install`

То есть как и написано в документации [http_push](https://pushmodule.slact.net).

Answer (score 1):

Вы скачали исходники модуля и nginx, распаковали и то и другое, потом вас просят при configure  указать путь к модулю который вы скачали и распаковали. Где тут можно ошибиться?

Comment: Задача и в самом деле не такая простая, как кажется, я сегодня это прошел (вроде бы успешно).

Для сборки потребовалась доустановка других библиотек; собранный таким образом nginx не содержит некоторых других модулей, например - ssl, необходимого для https; добавление модуля ssl требует доустановки Open SSL; скомпилированная библиотека Open SSL устанавливает себя в папку /usr/local/ssl, где ее не находит nginx при сборке, явное указание пути к библиотеке решает проблему на проверке include, но другая проверка все равно не видит эту библиотеку; и так далее.

Бег с препятствиями какой-то :-)